# If I want to learn to count in another base to calculate primality, which one should I try?

Tags: prime-numbers

I've heard base 12 is better, but what about base 30 ?

Learning multiplication tables in another base would be quite fastidious, so I don't know if that already been tried before...

(I don't know what sort of tags I should put on this one)

Comment: In general there are n(n+1)/2 entries in the multiplication table of base n (because you don't need to memorise a*b if you know b*a). As paw has answered, this would only help you to find smaller prime factors, and would not be efficient to determine the primality of a number because you'd have to convert between bases which would only complicate matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd try base six, which has instant divisibility tests for divisibility $2$ and $3$ and a sum-of-digits tests for divisibility by $5$, and an alternating sum of digits test for divisibility by $7$.  Also its multiplication table has only $36$ entries.  (Your idea of base thirty has instant tests for $2, 3, 5$ and sum/alternating sum tests for $29, 31$.  But in base thirty your multiplication table has $900$ entries to learn.)

To be honest though, the heart of (hard) primality testing has to do with finding large prime factors, and I don't see any base helping much with that.

Comment: +1 for the second paragraph. Finding small prime factors is easy in any base.